# How to perform dynamic calculation in html table column when pressed button in other table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Note:There are three column in table namely myTable which has item and plus and minus button basically i want to perform calculation in another table namely tablefinaldata whenever i click plus button in myTable that particular item should add in tablefinaldata (I have already done that).But whenever i add that particular item again then it would not take new row but increase quantity incrementally.

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover table-bordered" id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                   <td>
                                        <h5> Code</h5>
                                    </td>
                                    <td >
                                        <h5>Item </h5>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h5> Price</h5>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h5> Quantity</h5>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="setdata">
                            </tbody>
                            </table>
   //tablefinalda
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover table-bordered" id="tablefinaldata">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr ><td>
            <h5> Code</h5>
        </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h5> Item</h5>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h5> Price</h5>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h5> Quantity</h5>
                                    </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id="tablefinalbody">

                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

    //Scripting
function addItem(val, name) {

      var table2 = $("#setfinaldata");
                table2.empty();
                var Newdata = "<tr>" +
                "<th>" + val + ";</th>" +
                "<th>"+ name +";</th>" +
                "<th>1;</th>"
                + "</tr>";
                var a1 = new Array();
                a1 = Newdata.split(";");
                var markup = "<tr><th>"+a1[0].toString()+"</th><th>"+a1[1].toString()+"</th><th>"+a1[2].toString()+"</th></tr>";
                $("#tablefinalbody").append(markup);

                //table2.append(Newdata);
                //table2.append(tr);

            }
```

Comment: Can you please tell me that you want to append a new row in another table?

Comment: Nope I have already append new row as you see in scripting i just want to increase quantity in table whenever same item selected

Comment: Tell me that the code of every item is unique or not?

Comment: Yes item code is unique and name also

Comment: Okay wait for a while. I am working on this. and tell me that from where you add item. buttons I guess

Comment: SetData.empty();

        for (var a = 0; a < dataList.length; a++) {
            var data = "<tr >" +

                "<th>" + dataList[a].Item_code + "</th>" +
                "<th>" + dataList[a].Item_Name + "</th>" +
                "<th>1</th> <th><button type='button'  onclick=\"addItem('" + dataList[a].Item_code + "','" + dataList[a].Item_Name + "')\" class='btn btn-primary'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'/></button> <button type='button'  class='btnSelect'  class='btn btn-primary'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'/></button></th>"

Comment: I have solved this issue ..Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my own problem.
Back then if anyone have this type of problem so the solution is here:

```
function addItem(val, name) {

        var qty = parseFloat($('#tablefinaldata tr:contains(' + val + ')').find("#itemqty").html());
        var UnitPrice = parseFloat($('#tablefinaldata tr:contains(' + val + ')').find("#itemqprice").html());

        if ($('#tablefinaldata th:contains(' + val + ')').length) {


            //alert(qty);
            var addqty = qty + 1;
            $('#tablefinaldata tr:contains(' + val + ')').find("#itemqty").html(addqty);
            PriceSum(UnitPrice,addqty);



            }
            else {
            var table2 = $("#setfinaldata");
            table2.empty();
            var Newdata = "<tr>" +
            "<th>" + val + "</th>" +
            "<th>" + name + "</th>" +
            "<th id='itemprice'>1</th>"
            + "<th id='itemqty'>1</th>"
            + "</tr>";
            $("#tablefinalbody").append(Newdata);

        }



        //var a1 = new Array();
        //a1 = Newdata.split(";");
        //var markup = "<tr><th>"+a1[0].toString()+"</th><th>"+a1[1].toString()+"</th><th>"+a1[2].toString()+"</th></tr>";


        //table2.append(Newdata);
        //table2.append(tr);

    }
```

Comment: Anyone having subjected issue please used above function